# Does the set of all formal Laurent series form an ordered field?

Tags: ordered-fields

Let $R$ be an ordered field. Consider the set $R[[x]]:=\{\sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_nx^n:a_n \in R\}$

**Addition:**
$\sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_nx^n+\sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}}b_nx^n:=
\sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}}(a_n+b_n)x^n$

**Multiplication:**
$\sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_nx^n \times \sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}}b_nx^n:=
\sum_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}}(a_nb_n)x^n$

Does these operations on $R[[x]]$ makes it a field?

1. Have I correctly defined the multiplication?
2. Is the notation $R[[x]]$, i.e does the notation $R[[x]]$ have some other meaning? 
   If yes, is there any standard notation for this set?
3. What order relation can be defined on $R[[x]]$ in order to turn it into an ordered field?

*My motive is to show that $R[[x]]$ is Cauchy Complete but is not Order Complete(i.e lub property)*

---

**Edit:** As said by @ the multiplication defined above doesn't even make it an integral domain.

So I am changing the set to $R[[x]]:=\{\sum_\limits{k=-n}a_kx^k: a_k \in R, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$  and multiplication as defined in the answers.

Comment: The set of formal Laurent series *is* a field, but note that 1/ there must be only finitely many coefficients with negative power. 2/ As David Ullrich wrote, the product is not defined this way. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series, to begin with.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut If the multiplication is restricted to functions with poles then how is it a multiplication on $R[[x]]$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Wait, how do you define $R[[X]]$??? For me, $R[[X]]=\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nX^n \}$ and $R((X))=\{\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty a_nX^n \text{ with } n_0\in\Bbb Z \}$. If you have *formal* series with infinitely many terms both ways, how do you define the product? To me, it looks like everything in the question is wrong, or at least has nothing to do with the terms used.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Your definition of $R[[x]]$ is the same as in the question, hence the same as what I was assuming in my answer. How you define the product, indeed whether it's possible, is not clear to me

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Not the same. In the question, $n\in\Bbb Z$, whereas in my definition (which is not only mine, by the way), $n\in\Bbb N$, and with this the product is well defined. Likewise the product is well defined for formal Laurent series with finitely many negatives powers, and they form a field. (and by the way, as it's a field, it has a closure field, the [field of Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series)).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I missed the $n=0$, sorry.

Comment: After the edit: the answer by Vercassivelaunos explains the notation and gives you the correct definition of multiplication. Now are you just asking how to define the order?

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Yes yes.

Comment: And is $R$ the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No R is any ordered field

Comment: Ah, I see you specified that in the question, sorry. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define an order, it suffices to say which elements are $\geq 0$, since then we can define $a\leq b$ if and only if $(b-a)\geq 0$. (And then one needs to check that this order actually gives us an ordered field.)

One way to define the order is this: a formal Laurent series in $R((x))$, where $R$ is an ordered field, is $\geq 0$ if and only if it is $0$ or $c_n \geq 0$ in $R$, where $n$ is the least power of $x$ with nonzero coefficient $c_n$.

This ordering makes lower powers of $x$ "more significant", so you can think of it as an ordering of $R((x))$ in which $x$ is positive and infinitesimal.

Comment: I could not understand what you meant in the last paragraph. If possible will you explain it

Comment: What about it is unclear to you?

Comment: "Ordering makes lower powers of x "more significant"," In what sense? 

Also by this ordering how is $x$ infinitesimal?

Comment: @Saikat we have $0<\dots<x^3<x^2<x<r$ for every positive $r$ in $R$.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. Then can I tell this field is non archimedean?

Comment: Yes, that's right. We also have $1<2<3<\dots<x^{-1}$.

Comment: I have thought something of my own. Please take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977857/rx-set-of-formal-laurent-series-is-an-ordered-field-which-is-cauchy-comple)

Comment: I was going to say this gives a very "natural" non-archimedean field...

Comment: Can we introduce full ordering for an infinitely-large X? I think, no, but what kind of ordering we can introduce?

Comment: Something like Hardy fields?

Comment: @Anixx What is full ordering? Do you mean: can we linearly order $R((x))$ in such a way that $x$ is infinitely large"?

Comment: Yes. You proposed for an infinitely small version.

Comment: @Anixx I don't know the answer to this question off the top of my head. Maybe you should ask it as a separate question. It seems to me that there are only two "natural" linear orders: the one I described and its dual where $x$ is infinitesimal and negative. It's possible there's a theorem that these are the only two, but you probably need some continuity condition, e.g. to ensure than an "infinite sum" of positive elements is positive when this makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb R[[X]]$ is usually reserved for formal power series. Formal Laurent series are denoted $\mathbb R((X))$. However, they look different than your version. The main difference: you defined multiplication componentwise, essentially making your ring the same as $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb R}$, the ring of real valued maps on the integers (each component $a_nx^n$ of the series corresponds to the fact that $n\mapsto a_n$). This ring is not a field. It's not even an integral domain, since $(X)\cdot(X^2)=0$, for instance, so we have zero-divisors.

The usual way to make the Laurent series into a field (assuming we are considering coefficients from a field, which we do here) is to stipulate that they may only have a finite amount of negative powers and to define multiplication as

$$\left(\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_k X^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=-m}^\infty b_k X^k\right):=\sum_{k=-(n+m)}^\infty \sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_j X^k.$$

The reason for the finite amount of negative powers is to make the second sum finite, since infinite sums are not well defined in general.

As for a suitable ordering, you can define a positive cone $P\subset\mathbb R((X))$ as the set of all formal Laurent series whose leading coefficient (meaning the one with the smalles index) is nonnegative. With the ordering $f\geq g:\Leftrightarrow f-g\in P$ you get an ordered field.

Comment: How do I define an order relation in this field? Which will make it an Ordered Field.

Comment: You can define that a formal Laurent series over an ordered field ($\mathbb R$, for instance) is nonnegative if its leading coefficient (the one with the smalles index) is nonnegative. With the ordering $f\geq g:\Leftrightarrow f-g~\textrm{nonnegative}$, you get an ordered field.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's *not* a field with the multiplication you defined! The multiplicative identity is $\sum z^n$, hence $z$ is a non-zero element with no multiplicative inverse.

Where did this come from? Offhand I don't see how to define a multiplication that makes $R[[x]]$ into a field. The natural multiplication for formal *power series* is $$\left(\sum a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum b_n x^n\right)=\sum_n\left(\sum_{j+k=n}a_jb_k\right)x^n,$$but of course that doesn't converge for formal Laurent series...

Comment: How can I make this field an ordered field?

Comment: @Saikat **What** field? Did you glance at what I wrote? Maybe skim the first sentence???

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question according to the answers.

Comment: Now considering the field with the new definitions. How can I turn it into an ordered field?